# Unable to figure out the source for the bad_alloc error

Tags: ros, errors

I am getting a `bad_alloc` error when I try to use the `costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS::getRobotPose` function inside the `makePlan` function. Interestingly, if I call the same function from inside the `initialize` function (instead from inside the `makePlan` function), no error pops up.

I am attaching the relevant functions from my `source` code file.

```
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
#include <my_global_planner/global_planner.h>
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include <queue>
#include<math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include<visualization_msgs/Marker.h>

//register this planner as a BaseGlobalPlanner plugin
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(global_planner::GlobalPlanner, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)

using namespace std;

namespace global_planner {

  GlobalPlanner::GlobalPlanner (){

  }

  GlobalPlanner::GlobalPlanner(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros){
    initialize(name, costmap_ros);

  }

  void GlobalPlanner::initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros){

    nh_ = ros::NodeHandle{"~abcd"};
    
    costmap_ros  = costmap_ros;
    costmap_ros_ = costmap_ros->getCostmap(); 

    size_x = costmap_ros_->getSizeInCellsX(); 
    size_y = costmap_ros_->getSizeInCellsY();

    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped global_pose_;
    costmap_ros->getRobotPose(global_pose_);

    cout << "global_pose_.x: " << global_pose_.pose.position.x << " global_pose_.y: " << global_pose_.pose.position.y << endl;

    cout << "Sleeping for 3 seconds!" << endl;
    ros::Duration(3.0).sleep();

    cout << "global_frame: " << costmap_ros->getGlobalFrameID() << endl;

    global_plan_pub = nh_.advertise<nav_msgs::Path>("my_global_path", 1 );
    goal_marker_pub = nh_.advertise<visualization_msgs::Marker>("goal_markers", 10);

    marker_id_cnt = 0 ;

    update_map_bounds();


    //pose_sub = nh_.subscribe("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1000, &GlobalPlanner::initialpose_callback, this);
 
    //pose_sub = nh_.subscribe("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1000, boost::bind(&GlobalPlanner::initialpose_callback, this, _1));

  }

bool GlobalPlanner::makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal,  std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan ){

    //Djikstra's Algorithm
    __uint32_t mx_i, my_i, mx_f, my_f;

    print_world_params(start, goal, mx_i, my_i, mx_f, my_f);

    Point curr_point = Point{mx_i, my_i};

    Point goal_point = Point{goal.pose.position.x, goal.pose.position.y};

    bool reached = false;

    //srand((__uint32_t)time(0));

    cout << "Testing costmap_ros for consistency!" << endl;

    cout << "ros_costmap->getGlobalFrameID(): " << costmap_ros->getGlobalFrameID() << endl;
    cout << "Sleeping for 2 seconds!" << endl;
    ros::Duration(2.0).sleep();

    cout << "Trying to fetch global_pose of the robot!" << endl;
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped global_pose_;
    costmap_ros->getRobotPose(global_pose_);

    cout << "global_pose.x: " << global_pose_.pose.position.x << " global_pose_.y: " << global_pose_.pose.position.y  << endl;
    
    
    //generate_next_goal();
    
    return true;

  }
```

I am also attaching the relevant `header` file -

```
/** include the libraries you need in your planner here */
/** for global path planner interface */
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d_ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_2d.h>
#include <nav_core/base_global_planner.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>
#include <angles/angles.h>
#include <base_local_planner/world_model.h>
#include <base_local_planner/costmap_model.h>
#include <map>
#include<nav_msgs/Path.h>


#ifndef GLOBAL_PLANNER_CPP
#define GLOBAL_PLANNER_CPP



namespace global_planner {

    class GlobalPlanner : public nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner {

        struct Point {
            
                __uint32_t x, y; 

                bool operator==(const Point &p1 ) const{   return ((p1.x == x) && (p1.y == y));  }   
                
                bool operator<(const Point &p1 ) const{    return ((p1.x < x) || (p1.x == x && p1.y < y) ) ;  }   

            };

        
        struct Cell {

            Point point; 
            __uint32_t cost_till_now;

            bool operator<(const Cell &c1) const {
                
                
                return (c1.cost_till_now < cost_till_now || (c1.cost_till_now == cost_till_now && c1.point < point));

            }
        
        };



        public:

            GlobalPlanner();
            
            GlobalPlanner(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);
            void initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros);
            bool makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start,const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal,std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan);

            

        private: 


            double heu(Point p1, Point p2);
            void update_planner_plan(std::vector<Point> &path_points, std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> &plan, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped &goal); 
            void publish_global_path(const std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped> &plan, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped &goal);
            bool print_cell(const Cell &cell);
            bool make_straight_plan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal,  std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan);
            void print_world_params(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped &start, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped &goal, __uint32_t &mx_i, __uint32_t &my_i, __uint32_t &mx_f, __uint32_t &my_f);
            bool generate_straight_path(const Point &p1, const Point &p2);
            Point generate_next_goal();
            bool makePlanOne(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start,const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal,std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan);
            bool is_inside_robot_footprint(const Point &p);
            Point initialpose_callback(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped::ConstPtr &msg);
            void update_map_bounds();


            costmap_2d::Costmap2D* costmap_ros_;
            costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS *costmap_ros;
            __uint32_t size_x, size_y;
            __uint32_t map_xi, map_xf, map_yi, map_yf;
            ros::Publisher global_plan_pub, goal_marker_pub;
            ros::Subscriber pose_sub;
            ros::NodeHandle nh_;
            int marker_id_cnt;
    };

};

#endif
```

EDIT ONE - Attaching the error message

```
`[ INFO] [1623877214.383936978, 92.753000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "static"
[ INFO] [1623877214.399754683, 92.769000000]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1623877214.609456022, 92.979000000]: Resizing costmap to 4000 X 4000 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1623877214.758182943, 93.127000000]: Received a 4000 X 4000 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1623877214.758233616, 93.127000000]: Subscribing to updates
[ INFO] [1623877214.763301804, 93.132000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "inflation"
global_pose_.x: 0.0127673 global_pose_.y: -0.00185759
Sleeping for 3 seconds!
[ WARN] [1623877216.034654901, 94.401000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 1.0000Hz... the loop actually took 1.2430 seconds
global_frame: map
x_mx: 1691 x_mn: 2307
y_mn: 1692 y_mx: 2308
[ INFO] [1623877218.021871851, 96.385000000]: local_costmap: Using plugin "obstacles_laser"
[ INFO] [1623877218.026462101, 96.390000000]:     Subscribed to Topics: laser
[ INFO] [1623877218.038852471, 96.402000000]: local_costmap: Using plugin "inflation"
[ INFO] [1623877218.073365799, 96.437000000]: Created local_planner dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS
[ INFO] [1623877218.080402759, 96.444000000]: Sim period is set to 0.05
[ WARN] [1623877218.083561377, 96.447000000]: Parameter max_trans_vel is deprecated (and will not load properly). Use max_vel_trans instead.
[ WARN] [1623877218.084195753, 96.447000000]: Parameter min_trans_vel is deprecated (and will not load properly). Use min_vel_trans instead.
[ WARN] [1623877218.084750167, 96.448000000]: Parameter max_rot_vel is deprecated (and will not load properly). Use max_vel_theta instead.
[ WARN] [1623877218.085114421, 96.449000000]: Parameter min_rot_vel is deprecated (and will not load properly). Use min_vel_theta instead.
[ INFO] [1623877219.082219761, 97.444000000]: Recovery behavior will clear layer 'obstacles'
[ INFO] [1623877219.087005348, 97.448000000]: Recovery behavior will clear layer 'obstacles'
[ INFO] [1623877219.112662972, 97.473000000]: odom received!
[ WARN] [1623877220.007202261, 98.365000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 1.0000Hz... the loop actually took 1.2070 seconds
Inside the make_plan function!
Hello World!
(int)costmap_2d::LETHAL_OBSTACLE: 254
(int)costmap_2d::NO_INFORMATION: 255
(int)costmap_2d::FREE_SPACE: 0
Sleeping for 2 seconds!

Printing start pose and goal pose: 
w_i: (0.01278,-0.00185759) m_i: (2000,1999)
w_f: (-9.51565,0.0048027) m_f: (1809,2000)

Testing costmap_ros for consistency!
[move_base-1] process has died [pid 3322, exit code -11, cmd /home/skpro19/catkin_ws/devel/lib/move_base/move_base /odom:=odometry/filtered __name:=move_base __log:=/home/skpro19/.ros/log/d4e95946-cee5-11eb-8e7f-c8e2656b0bb1/move_base-1.log].
log file: /home/skpro19/.ros/log/d4e95946-cee5-11eb-8e7f-c8e2656b0bb1/move_base-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
done`
```

Comment: What is the exact, verbatim error you're getting? Doesn't it have a line number??

Comment: @Chuck I have updated the post with the error message.  The error is arising because of using the `getRobotPose` function inside the `makePlan` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no export in C++, but this line:

```
  void GlobalPlanner::initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros){

    nh_ = ros::NodeHandle{"~abcd"};
    
    costmap_ros  = costmap_ros;
```

(the last) you are setting the costmap_ros parameter to itself, so I don't think you are setting the costmap_ros of the object so when you get to makePlan, costmap_ros is pointing to something random. Try renaming the costmap_ros parameter in the function to cm_ros and change the line to costmap_ros = cm_ros;

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks!